# Ubuntu 17.10 does not detect an HP Laser Jet printer connected via USB

Tags: usb, hp, laserjet

Ubuntu 17.10 does not detect an HP LJ 1022 printer connected to a computer via a USB cable.

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 09da:000a A4Tech Co., Ltd. Optical Mouse Opto 510D / OP-620D
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: English, please.

Comment: Why do you think it's not detected? Please [edit] your post to include the output of `lsusb` with the printer attached. thank you for helping us help you!